# apache2 server online, but cannot access it on an Android device

Tags: apache, metasploit

I am trying to learn Metasploit using Kali Linux on a Virtual Machine. I learned that payloads can be "carried" through an Apache server. But the problem is, when I try to access the Apache server through my Android phone, it seems that it cannot reach the server even though I entered the details correctly and the server has started. Anyone knows what am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a security question or about metasploit or payloads. This sounds like a really basic connection issue to your server. Start a network troubleshooting process to narrow down the problem.